# Pull file/dir from remote machine Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to pull file or directory from a remote linux machine to Jenkins machine. Is there any Jenikns plugin available?

I am using one plugin "Publish Over SSH" and I am able to transfer files but not receive. I don't want to write/expose password to scp command line. Please suggest a way.

Answer (score 0):

probably you're looking for this https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to expose the credentials in the script. You can manage those in jenkins and pass them as parameters which can be hidden in log. Refer the links below.
https://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/Jenkins+Enterprise/InjectingSecrets
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin